# sql query result to csv file directly from console

Tags: sql, csv

I want to export `select` query result with two columns to `csv` file. I don't have phpmyadmin or tools like this. I have to run my query directly from console. Can someone give me a hint how can I do this?

Comment: What console are you using?

Comment: usual terminal in ubuntu 14.04. mysql version is 5.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to use this command:

```
SELECT field_1,field_2
FROM table_name
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```